# LaunchDaemons Starting Before IP Addresses Have Been Assigned

Tags: macos, launchd

I’m working on an annoying problem with my Mac mini (running OS X 10.9). I have postfix and pfctl scheduled to load as system daemons using launchd, and they do so successfully. However, they do so between the Ethernet link going up and IP addresses being assigned. As a result, pfctl cannot properly resolve the `self` keyword and only adds the localhost equivalents to pf’s rule list. Similarly, postfix terminates because it cannot reach the network interface.

Reloading each daemon after IP addresses have been assigned corrects the problem until the next reboot. Is there a way to delay when these daemons start? My system log shows I would only need to delay them by 20 seconds, at most. For the record, I also had this problem on OS X 10.6, 10.7, and 10.8.

Comment: As a test, I added the `<KeepAlive>` key with the `NetworkState` boolean value to the plist, and this did not work as expected. postfix failed to start at all, and pfctl loaded the defined rule set without waiting for proper IP addresses.

Comment: I’ve fixed the pf problem by reconfiguring the rule set to use a dynamic table for IP addresses, but the original problem remains for postfix (and dovecot and httpd).